# blueimp-gallery.js and the -min.js version

Tags: jquery, gallery, carousel, blueimp

So I have an album wedding site that I am doing and everything seems to be fine except that I have three galleries.

1) Is the one that's giving me problems, I have a normal lightbox blueimp images that each time one of the images gets clicked, the scroll bar gets hidden (which is fine by me), however when pressing ESC or the X the scroll bars do not get re-activated.

If I use blueimp-gallery.js the scroll bars appear and disappear. BUT the videos on the second video-gallery do not get shown at all anymore.  If I use blueimp-gallery.min.js (the min version) the video gets shown as a carousel but the scrolling issue starts again.

Is there any tweaking (besides disablescroll: !0 to !1 or hidePageScrollbars: !0 to !1) that I should be doing?

I'm stuck on this one and can't do anything about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the problem was that I was trying to change the context in the .js file and not in the actual initialization of the gallery.  It is working now.